# JMeter: Can we use nested Loop Counter twice within IF Controller

Tags: jmeter, nested-loops

My test plan looks like this

TEST_PLAN

-Thread_group: (user: 1, ramp: 1, loop:70)

--Loop_Controller_1(loop:1)
--Loop_Counter

-- HTTP request1: go to page_1

-IF_Controller1 ( Loop_Counter=5)
-- HTTP request2: go to page_2

-IF_Controller2 ( Loop_Counter=67)
-- Loop_Controller_2 (loop:3)
--- HTTP request3: go to page_2

Here the condition is based on the Loop_Counter, if loop_counter is 5, IF_Contoller1 is executed. When loop_counter is 15, If_controller2 is met, Loop_controller_2 should be executed for 3 loops. All 3 http request inputs are read from 3 different CSV files.

When executed, http request 1 is invoked only 4 times, not sure how this `enter code here`number is achieved.

Is this correct way of implementation, or anything missing/wrong?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Implementation looks good, however scope of CSV Data Set Config matters.

I would recommend adding any of your CSV Data Config Element **as a child** of the request you're trying to parametrize. Also check `Recycle on EOF`, `Stop thread on EOF` and especially `Sharing Mode` parameters.

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for more details.

As an option you can post your .jmx file and any CSV files used somewhere so it would be more clear what's going on in your case.